# How to apply opacity to a control after composition

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, windows-8.1-universal

my question is about WPF and/or Windows 8.1 Xaml.

I have a user control that contains and parent grid, which contains 2 child controls that overlap one another. I want to make the control see-through, but using the opacity property on the grid has a problem: When I set it, I can see one of the sibling controls through the other one. What I really need is a way to turn the whole thing partially transparent after it finishes laying out the two sibling controls. There must be a way to do this.

EDIT: Per Mark's comment, here is some code that illustrates the problem. If you run this code you will see that with opacity turned on for the grid, you can see the blue rectangle through the yellow one. If the opacity were being applied after the rectangles were rendered you would only see the yellow rectangle in the center cell.

```
    <Grid Opacity="0.5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't post any code.

Comment: If you want center cell only have yellow color, this code done for you. If you see blue color, there maybe have some implicit style being apply for your rectangle.

Comment: set the opacity of the grid in the loaded event of the grid.